# NoClassDefFoundError Jar Error for org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I have seen this question asked a lot, but I still can't figure out a solution to it. Well a solution that works for me. I have a project that is using Apache POI, and I made sure to include all the external JARs. The project compiles and runs fine in eclipse but when I run the jar with "`java -jar Test.jar`" I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet

I'm not sure if this is useful information, but I created a lib folder for my project and put the poi library in there. This means that the dependcies are in the JAR file when I create it, I figured I should mention this because I saw a few solutions about just having your external jars right next to your executable jar. I also tried setting my classpath to the directory of the project.

What do I seem to be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Apache POI JAR file](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) is not on your runtime classpath. Rebuild `Test.jar` with the following manifest entry in the `MANIFEST.MF` file

```
Class-Path: poi-3.9-20121203.jar
```

Comment: I attemped this, but am still getting the same error. This is what I put in my Manifest

Class-Path: lib/poi-3.9/poi-3.9-20121203.jar

I still ran my jar with "java -jar Test.jar"

Comment: Looks ok, check that you have a newline character at the end of the manifest file. Also check that the manifest was correctly included (by unjarring it to a temp folder). Finally check that path to poi jar file is correct

Comment: I have unjarred and checked the MANIFEST.MF file. The file was included, it had a newline, and I'm pretty sure the path is correct. Is the classpath from the MANIFEST file or from the project directory?

Comment: The classpath is relative from where the jar is being run

Comment: Thanks I'm an idiot. My code compiled a little bit further so I think I have to just include all poi jars. Right now the jar file has to be in my project directory because it has to find the external jars. Is there a way to prevent that, so the user can just run the jar anywhere. Let's say I include all the external jars inside my jar file. So inside my jar I have my lib folder. Is there a way to set the class path to reference that, and not the directory the jar is in?

Comment: You can use a `Rsrc-Class-Path` for that where all the required jars are embedded in a single JAR file. IDEs such as Eclipse will do this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When the `java -jar [filename].jar` command fails, it's almost always because of one of two things:

1. Your MANIFEST.MF is messed up and doesn't list dependencies properly.  Make sure all jar dependencies in your manifest file point to jars, relative to your jar's parent directory.
2. You are missing .class files, either in your specific jar or in one you depend on.  Ensure your jar contains `org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.class` or that your manifest hierarchy points to a jar that contains that class.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide classpath in Jar file's manifest file. [**See this official doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

**An Example**

We want to load classes in MyUtils.jar into the class path for use in MyJar.jar. These two JAR files are in the same directory.

We first create a text file named `Manifest.txt` with the following contents:

```
Class-Path: MyUtils.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if your target jar (`Test.jar`) is a fat jar containing all the required dependencies.

```
$ jar tf Test.jar
```

You should see your `lib/` folder there containing all the required dependencies (including Apache POI). If that's the case do what others suggested, add Apache POI to your `MANIFEST.MF`.

About having your jar dependencies in a separate folder, as you suggested, that's also possible. Imagine your dependencies where stored in a `lib/` folder outside your `Test.jar`. You could run your code with this command:

```
$ java -cp ".:lib/*" org.Test.Main
```

It simply adds all the .jars within lib/ folder to your classpath. In this case you also need to specify the name of the main class (full name).

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem and tried to google it..

i have found out that i have to read the error log

I cant save my file to .xls so
in my case after reading the error i found that a jar file is missing
i just added the jar file poi-3.7-20101029 located in the ext folder of my ireport

ex.YourIReportFolder/ireport/modules/ext-poi.x.x-xxxx

hope this helps :)